# How to detect one Path Collision

Tags: java, android, canvas, path, collision

I have a path on canvas, I want to know if the path cross itself??

```
 private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
    float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
            float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
              if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
                mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
                mX = x;
                mY = y;
   }
}
```

I want to know if mPath is touch itself??

See below : green path has no collision and red has collision point

I need a function like this

```
public Boolean isPathCollision(Path path)
```

thanks
[image: collision mPath sample]

Answer (score 0):

this is an old question but i was working on this and let me share the solution so maybe someone can get help ..
but the question is quite confusing as if you mean that you want o detect a touch on a path then this code will work

```
        for (int i = 0; i < pathLists.size(); i++) {
//the loop on all the path on the screen // you have to store every path to a list
//Recft bound will get the RectF of every path with the help of loop.
                RectF boundrySlice=new RectF();
                pathLists.get(i).computeBounds(boundrySlice, true);
//here is the detection, the event x, y are your finger x,y axist,
//so implement this code in touch event in MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                if(boundrySlice.contains(event.getX(),event.getY())){

                    selectedPath= i;// where selectedPath is declared Globally.
// i is the index of path that is selected,
                    
                    break;              
                }
            }
```